Invalid Field fieldName
This is the error:
Line: 110, Column: 1
System.SObjectException: Invalid field Graphic_Designer__r.Copywriter_Buddy__c for Account

This is line 110:
else if(currentWorkTicket.Account__r.get(buddyName) != NULL)

This is the code that would populate the variable buddyName
switch on currentWorkTicket.skills__c {
            when 'Copywriter', 'Copywriter AD', 'Copywriter Senior', 'PPC Copy', 'Web Copy' {
                positionName = 'Copywriter__c';
                buddyName = 'Copywriter__r.Graphic_Designer_Buddy__c';
            } when 'Graphic Designer', 'Graphic Designer AD', 'Graphic Designer Senior', 'Web Design' {
                positionName = 'Graphic_Designer__c';
                buddyName = 'Graphic_Designer__r.Copywriter_Buddy__c';
            } when else {
                positionName = NULL;
            }
        }

The Graphic_Designer__r is a lookup from an account to a user, Copywriter_Buddy__c is a lookup from a user to another user, the api names are all correct, I can't figure out why this is firing! Thank you for any help!
This class is run Without Sharing

I believe SObject's .get() is only for fields on the object itself. For getting at related data dynamically, I think you need to use .getSObject() ( or .getSObjects() if it's a parent-child relationship you're trying to traverse).

Derek is correct. I've linked a couple of questions that go into more detail.
